# What do the on_delete options in Ecto.Migrations.references/2 do?

Tags: elixir, ecto

The [Ecto documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#references/2) describes the options available to `references/2`, but does not document what those options do. The options available are:

- `:nothing`
- `:delete_all`
- `:nilify_all`
- `:restrict`

What do they do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually a SQL question at root.

https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/52f9d27a7ad86442f442bad2f7ebd19ba09ddc61/lib/ecto/adapters/myxql/connection.ex#L902-L905

The [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/ddl-constraints.html) outlines these options clearly:

- `:nothing` - if any referencing rows still exist when the constraint is checked, an error is raised; this is the default behavior if you do not specify anything.
- `:delete_all` - specifies that when a referenced row is deleted, row(s) referencing it should be automatically deleted as well
- `:nilify_all` - causes the referencing column(s) in the referencing row(s) to be set to `nil` when the referenced row is deleted
- `:restrict` - prevents deletion of a referenced row. It will fail if there is a referenced object.

`:nothing` and `:restrict` are similar but:

> the essential difference between these two choices is that
>   [`:nothing`] allows the check to be deferred until later in the
>   transaction, whereas [`:restrict`] does not.

Comment: OK, so this is actually a SQL question then, not Ecto.