# When to use "nothing" or "restrict" for "on_delete" with Ecto?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384859/what-do-the-on-delete-options-in-ecto-migrations-references-2-do) but I don't understand this part:

> the essential difference between these two choices is that [:nothing] allows the check to be deferred until later in the transaction, whereas [:restrict] does not.

When should I know I need to defer or not the check since I know I need to check anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the DB you are using.

If you are using MySQL they're exactly the same because the checks are always done at the start of transaction.

> NO ACTION: A keyword from standard SQL. In MySQL, equivalent to
>   RESTRICT. The MySQL Server rejects the delete or update operation for
>   the parent table if there is a related foreign key value in the
>   referenced table. Some database systems have deferred checks, and NO
>   ACTION is a deferred check. In MySQL, foreign key constraints are
>   checked immediately, so NO ACTION is the same as RESTRICT.
>   Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

If we look at the Postgres documentation we see that there is a difference.

> Restricting and cascading deletes are the two most common options.
>   RESTRICT prevents deletion of a referenced row. NO ACTION means that
>   if any referencing rows still exist when the constraint is checked, an
>   error is raised; this is the default behavior if you do not specify
>   anything. (The essential difference between these two choices is that
>   NO ACTION allows the check to be deferred until later in the
>   transaction, whereas RESTRICT does not.) 
>   Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/ddl-constraints.html

I was also curious as to why you might want to pick one over the other and the answer seems to be performance. Look at this mail thread:

> As for why you might *want* a deferred check, the only practical use I
>   can think of is to delete a referenced row in the master table, then
>   insert a replacement row with the same key, before ending the
>   transaction.  In principle you could do that as a single UPDATE, but
>   it might be that your application logic makes it awkward to do so.
>   Source: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4271.1233022978%40sss.pgh.pa.us